# {PreviousPost} and {NextPost} not working on Tumblr

Tags: themes, tumblr

It seems like {PreviousPost} and {NextPost} is not working on Tumblr for creating custom themes.  Here's my code. Can someone point to my mistake...

```
<div>
    {block:PreviousPost}<a href="{PreviousPost}"><span>Previous Post</span></a>{/block:PreviousPost}
    {block:NextPost}<a href="{NextPost}"><span>Next Post</span></a>{/block:NextPost}
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to wrap it in `{block:PermalinkPagination}…{/block:PermalinkPagination}` blocks, like this:

```
{block:PermalinkPagination}
    {block:PreviousPost}
        <a rel="prev" href="{PreviousPost}">{lang:Previous Post}</a>
    {/block:PreviousPost}
    {block:NextPost}
        <a rel="next" href="{NextPost}">{lang:Next Post}<a/>
    {/block:NextPost}
{/block:PermalinkPagination}
```

Comment: just tried it and its not working. my {nextpage} and {previouspage} has been working. its just the posts that aren't.

Comment: I'm sorry I mystyped in name of block: `{block:PermalinkPagination}…{/block:PermalinkPagination}`

Comment: awesome. works now. weird that there is not such block displayed on the customs tumblr definition page.

Comment: use [**disattention theme guide**](http://disattention.com/labs/tumblr/theme-guide/) if something not working from official documentation